# python & postgresql: передача больших массивов данных в хранимые функции для выполнения многократного INSERT

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, insert, хранимые-процедуры

в python коде есть список списков

`arr = list()`

каждый элемент которого представляет собой список из 5 элементов `(int, str, str, int, str)`

хочу передать этот массив в хранимую процедуру postgresql и записать всё за 1 раз в БД, чтобы операция была максимально быстрой

использую библиотеку `psycopg2`:

выполняю передачу данных как:

```
cursor.callproc('add_records', id, arr)
```

хранимая процедура выглядит так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_records(
    in__id integer,
    in__data record_type[])
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_t (id, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, created_at, modified_at)
    SELECT
        in__id,
        r.*,
        NOW(),
        NOW()
    FROM UNNEST(in__data) AS r;
END;
$BODY$;
```

а тип `record_type`:

```
CREATE TYPE record_type AS
(
    f1 integer,
    f2 character varying,
    f3 character varying,
    f4 integer,
    f5 character varying
);
```

Но добавление в `table_t` не происходит даже нескольких записей.

Использование вместо `record_type` `anyarray` тоже не помогает

Подскажите в чём может быть дело?
Как делать многократные insert через хранимки в python?

Comment: Использовать COPY TO не пробовали? https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

Comment: т.е. сформировать таблицу в python и перелить ее в БД, а потом уже перенести из таблицы данные в нужную таблицу?